# how to get exact string value from delimited column value match in oracle database

Tags: oracle, contains

I have 2 tables

```
Table 1:
#######
ID  Location
1    India
2    Australia

Table 2:
############
Name   Locations
test1  India|North America
test2  Indiana|Australia
```

I used the below query to get the Name from table 2 if it contains Location in Locations of table 2.

```
select Name
from table2 t2 inner join table1 t1 
  on instr(t1.Location,t2.Locations,length(t1.Location)) >= 1;
```

But when executed it still gives me results for Indiana as well whereas it should just return me result for location India alone.

I tried using contains in query too, but contains takes second parameter as string but not as column name.

Is there any other approach on this?

Answer (score 1):

regexps always help in such cases

```
with 
    table1 (id, location) as (
        select 1, 'India' from dual union
        select 2, 'Australia' from dual 
    ),
    table2 (name, locations) as (
        select 'test1', 'India|North America' from dual union
        select 'test2', 'Indiana|Australia' from dual 
    )
select  *
from    table2 join table1 on 
            regexp_like (locations, '(^|\|)' || location || '(\||$)')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to look up location with delimiter, like this:

```
select Name from table2 t2 
inner join table1 t1 on instr(t2.Locations,t1.Location||'|') >= 1
```

Comment: this works but if the keyword to search is hutchings from the delimited value "a.hutchings | a.hutch" it should not return the value, but it is returning the above string too, i am looking for exact string match

Comment: This query doesn't work properly  if `Location`substring  will be placed at the end of `Locations`. To see it just replace 'India|North America' to 'North America|India'

Comment: The idea is correct, but to fix the issues demonstrated in comments, it needs to be refined a bit. You should compare `'|' || t1.Location || '|'` to `'|' || t2.Location || '|'` - either with `instr()` or, more common, with the `LIKE` comparison operator.